# Geo Nodes Shortcut: take out node to put it elsewhere

Tags: geometry-nodes, shortcut

Lets say I have node 1, node 2 and node 3. I used to know a shortcut where I could take out node 2 but keep the connection between 1 and 3. I believe it was something like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> but somehow the shortcut changed. Maybe it was replaced in some newer blender version. Does some one know the shortcut?

(I don't mean <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> which keeps the connection but deletes the node.)

Comment: Alt-left drag should do it.

Comment: Could be "detach links"... but no preset shortcut for it.

Comment: @JohnEason alt + left mouse button + drag? This only shifts my screen since I have "emulate middle mouse button" enabled and the alt button replaces the middle mouse button.

Comment: @Christoph It looks as if it's a function of the built-in (but not enabled by default) Node Wrangler addon. It's been enabled here for so long that I can't remember which are native commands and which are supplied by NR!

Comment: I don't know which shortcut you used to know, but as far as I know there is only the Alt + left drag shortcut and from the Node Wrangler add-on there is a shortcut Shift+Alt+D which makes a connection between node 1 and 3 and keeps the connection between node 1 and 2. But that doesn't help if you cannot use the Alt key. The function you want however is available through the menu _Node_ > _Detach Links_ and of course you can right-click it and assign your own shortcut.

Comment: I'm also using *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* (even I have the mouse) by Alt key ... probably time to move forward :) or change the shortcut. Alt+D was used natively by Blender, but from it was changed from version 3.64 LTS to Alt+Left mouse drag ... Node Wrangler uses shortcut only for *Detouch Output* socket by Shift+Alt+D.